# Zend_Http_Client SimpleXMLElement error

Tags: magento-1.7, xml

Sometimes when i visit my website's admin panel I get these spooky Warnings in my system.log:

```
ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 8: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 1  in /Users/PLAE_01/Documents/Projects/website-live/app/code/local/Mgt/Base/Model/Feed.php on line 79
ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():   in /Users/PLAE_01/Documents/Projects/website-live/app/code/local/Mgt/Base/Model/Feed.php on line 79
ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^  in /Users/PLAE_01/Documents/Projects/website-live/app/code/local/Mgt/Base/Model/Feed.php on line 79
```

I am running Magento 1.7 but am planning on a 1.9 upgrade soon. Does anybody know how I can go about solving these errors?